# Issues with gdbserver and stlink in configuring a mbed studio IDE development platform

Tags: embedded, mbed, gdbserver, st-link

I am currently working on configuring a Mbed Studio IDE development environment.

**Development Platform:** Ubuntu 20.04
**Hardware Platform:** NUCLEO-F401RE
**Mbed Tool Version:**

[image: mbed tool version]

**Issue:** While trying to start the debugger I get the following error. The issue appears to point to `gdbserver` and `STLink`

```
0001396:ERROR:gdbserver:Unexpected exception: STLink error (20): DP wait
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/gdbserver/gdbserver.py”, line 336, in run self.target.halt()
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/coresight/cortex_m.py”, line 473, in halt self.write_memory(CortexM.DHCSR, 
CortexM.DBGKEY | CortexM.C_DEBUGEN | CortexM.C_HALT)
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/coresight/cortex_m.py”, line 430, in write_memory self.ap.write_memory(addr, 
value, transfer_size)
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/probe/stlink_probe.py”, line 241, in write_memory
self._link.write_mem32(addr, conversion.u32le_list_to_byte_list([data]), self._apsel)
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/probe/stlink/stlink.py”, line 389, in write_mem32
self._write_mem(addr, data, Commands.JTAG_WRITEMEM_32BIT, self.MAXIMUM_TRANSFER_SIZE, apsel)
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/probe/stlink/stlink.py”, line 379, in _write_mem raise 
self._ERROR_CLASSESstatus 
pyocd.core.exceptions.TransferTimeoutError: STLink error (20): DP wait
Exception in thread gdb-packet-thread-port50000:
File “/home/xxxx/.config/Mbed Studio/mbed-studio-tools/python/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pyocd/utility/sockets.py”, line 55, in read return self.conn.recv(packet_size) 
AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘recv’ 
“0001396:ERROR:gdbserver:Unexpected exception: STLink error (20): DP wait”
```

Any insights toward resolving the issue is greatly appreciated.